# Issue templating classes in Java

Tags: java

Forgive me if my terminology on "templating" is incorrect I come from a c++ background. I was having issues with the default constructor. The compiler says "identifier expected" and I'm not understanding. Anyone know the answer?

So you know, GameObject has a HashMap named 'object' that is already initialized.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.Serializable; 
public class GameList<T, V> extends GameObject
{
    protected HashMap<T, V> list;
    public GameList<T, V>()
    {
        list = object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note in java it's generics, not templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
public GameList()
{
    list = object;   
}
```

You don't need to reiterate the `<T, V>` on the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code:

- You need to remove the argument list in the declaration of the constructor - Unlike C++, this list of type arguments is implied, and
- If `GameObject` has a `HashMap` object that does not have type parameters, you need to add a type cast: `list = (HashMap<T,V>)object;`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some useful best practices in addition to the mentioned ones above:

the line:

```
list = object;
```

Could be an error since **object** is not passed as a constructor argument, if you have object in your super class, then declare it protected there (it's most probably an error to have two pointers to the same instance).

If you want a copy of the object in the parent class (which I doubt), but anyway call

```
list = new HashMap<T, V>(object);
```

Also avoid calling a **List list**, a **Map map** and even worse: a **Map list** the variable name doesn't have any added value on its type, the program reader doesn't understand wht your variable is supposed to contain.

Similarily avoid **List userList**:

The best thing is to be the more possibly specific to allow an immediate code understanding and avoid unnecessary comments: Say what is in the list or map you declare eg.

```
Map<Long, User> connectedFreindsById;
List<User> friends;
```

Best Regards,
Zied Hamdi - http://1vu.fr

Comment: Java doesn't have pointers, and two variables referring to the same instance is most certainly not an error. Just try `Object x = new Object(); Object y = x;`.

Comment: Every computer has memory pointers. You should understand what is happening behind the wall in a program to be able to predict how it will behave. Java has pointers, you just don't see it: y and x point to the same memory adress, they are just a reference to a memory location. That's why when you change the x state, you can see the change in y (as long as you don't assign another pointer to y or x by doing x = z